# Conditionally remove an XML element

Tags: python, xml

```xml
<input>
      <signal dataType="Single" defaultValue="" gdsName="DSP_1/ctrlDsp1_OutOtherLane">
        <destSignal simulinkIoType="appicationIO" simulinkName="ctrlDsp1_InOtherLane/valveCtrlTrack"/>
      </signal>
</input>
<inp>
       <signal>..
        </signal>
</inp>
```

If these conditions are true then `<destSignal>` element has to be removed:

1. It has to iter through only `input` element
2. In `signal` element attribute `gdsName` should start with `DSP`
3. In `destSignal` element the attribute `simulinkIoType` should be `appicationIO`
4. Again in `destSignal` the attribute `simulinkName` should start with `ctrlDsp1`

```py
import string
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('C:/Users/swath/Downloads/s6cs.dsp')
root = tree.getroot()
for inputFrame in root.iter('inputFrame'):
    for j in root.iter('signal'):
        datatype=j.get('gdsName')
        if datatype.startswith('DSP'):
            for destSignal in root.iter('destSignal'):
                        simulink=destSignal.get('simulinkIoType')
                        name=destSignal.get('simulinkName')
                        if simulink == 'ApplicationIO' and name.startswith('ctrlDsp'):
                            root.remove(inputFrame)
                            
tree.write('new.xml')
```

I tried this and it's not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just say "it's not working". In what way is it not working? Are you getting error messages? The XML sample in the question is not well-formed.

Comment: It is better and much easier to implement such tasks via XSLT.

Comment: The python code and the XML doesn't match and it makes understanding what you want difficult. For example, you say if the conditions are true the `destSignal` needs to be removed, but in your code you're trying to remove `inputFrame`. Also, it's `inputFrame` in your python but `input` in the XML and conditions. It's `ApplicationIO` in the python and `appicationIO` (case and spelling differences) in the XML and conditions. Etc. However, I think the main problem is when you loop, you don't change context. For example, `for j in root.iter('signal')` should be `for j in inputFrame.iter('signal')`.

Comment: In addition to being easier in XSLT, it would be easier using xpath in lxml (which has full xpath 1.0 support which will come in handy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the element references in the code were referencing "root" element and not the signal element so the matches were not found. Also the example code is looking for inputFrame element and the sample input has "input" elements. Added some print statements to help debugging.

Here is cleaned up code that removes the matching elements from the XML file:

```python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('C:/Users/swath/Downloads/s6cs.dsp')
root = tree.getroot()
for inputFrame in root.iter('input'):
    for signal in inputFrame.iter('signal'):
        datatype = signal.get('gdsName')
        print('gdsname', datatype)
        if datatype.startswith('DSP'):
            for destSignal in signal.iter('destSignal'):
                simulink = destSignal.get('simulinkIoType')
                name = destSignal.get('simulinkName')
                print(f'  simulink {simulink} / simulinkName {name}')
                if simulink == 'applicationIO' and name.startswith('ctrlDsp'):
                    print('removed')
                    root.remove(inputFrame)
                            
tree.write('new.xml')
```

Given this sample XML input, the first input element will be removed and the second will be preserved in the new XML file.

**Input:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
    <input id="1">
        <signal dataType="Single" defaultValue="" gdsName="DSP_1/ctrlDsp1_OutOtherLane">
            <destSignal simulinkIoType="applicationIO" simulinkName="ctrlDsp1_InOtherLane/valveCtrlTrack"/>
        </signal>
    </input>
    <input id="2">
        <signal dataType="Single" defaultValue="" gdsName="XSP_1/ctrlDsp1_OutOtherLane">
            <destSignal simulinkIoType="applicationIO" simulinkName="ctrlDsp1_InOtherLane/valveCtrlTrack"/>
        </signal>
    </input>
</xml>
```

**Output:**

```xml
<xml>
    <input id="2">
        <signal dataType="Single" defaultValue="" gdsName="XSP_1/ctrlDsp1_OutOtherLane">
            <destSignal simulinkIoType="applicationIO" simulinkName="ctrlDsp1_InOtherLane/valveCtrlTrack" />
        </signal>
    </input>
</xml>
```

Comment: It works, but there is a whitespace in the closing tag. What is causing it and how to remove it. Thanks for help.

Comment: Does your input XML have a root element like in example I used or is it only a series of XML fragments starting with `<input>` elements?

Comment: It has root, similar to the example you have used.